# What happens when I send ajax request on a link?

Tags: ajax, hyperlink

```
<a id="link" href="http://google.com">Let's Go</a>

$("#link").on("click", function(){

    $.post("process.php",
                    {
                        x: pos.x,
                        y: pos.y
                    },
                    function(data, status){
                        // do something here
                });
            });

    });
```

What happens when I click on `Let's Go` link? Does the browser wait for request to be sent and get the results from `process.php` page? Or forgets about the request and follows the link immediately?

Answer (score 0):

`href` will override any JS function. So in your case it will just redirect to `http://google.com`. If you want it to ignore the `href`,then you need to use `e.preventDefault()` like this:

```
$("#link").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //... more code
});
```